# MySQL: ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table);

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I apologize if this question is stupid. Code is pretty easy to understand.

**Syntax error** occurs at last line. How can I overcome it?

```
    SELECT id
    FROM m_users
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp_students);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM (SELECT u.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM m_users u
     ) u
WHERE seqnum <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp_students)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: @user8555937 . . . `LIMIT` requires a constant in MySQL.